# Get AD Group name from the Email

Tags: c#, active-directory

I wonder, whether it is possible to grammatically get the AD Group (name) from the e-mail address of the group (the left part of the e-mail does not match to the group name)?

I need in my code the GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, groupName);
but it seems does not work with the e-mail as the input. It worked only with the group name on the input. There is also 3rd param - Identity type enum, but none of value seem to work with the e-mail address.

Exist there any solution how to get the group name (A way Like Outlook does (entering email and then pressing Ctrl+K) the group name is shown :) ?)

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking an Active Directory mail-enabled account should have a *proxyAdresses* LDAP attribute, so a simple query should work, i.e.:

```
var searchedEmail = "user@domain.com";
var ds = new DirectorySearcher($"proxyAddresses=smtp:{searchedEmail}", new string[] { "cn" });
Console.WriteLine(ds.FindOne().Properties["cn"][0]);
```

Comment: This will work. You may want to pull the `displayName` instead of `cn`. They're often the same, but don't have to be. Outlook uses the `displayName`.

Comment: Great, It is working! And I will take rather the DisplayName property, if used by Outlook. It is nice the second parameter is an array, so it can be added more properties... Would bee good  for me to look more in the DirectorySearcher, anyway thanks a lot for mentioning this!

Comment: Actually is it possible to do an opposite search - to  find user's email from the user's account name using the DirectorySearcher ?

Comment: Of course you can. For example: `var ds = new DirectorySearcher($"sAMAccountName={searchedUser}", new string[] { "mail" }); Console.WriteLine(ds.FindOne().Properties["mail"][0]);`